# How to graph a helix that starts at the origin

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

So i have this graph

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[54 {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10 + 12.5/54}, {t, -10, 10}],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{54, 0, 12.5}, Scaled[.015]]}]
]
```

Now this curve of the helix intersects the point $(54,0,12.5)$. I was wondering if anyone knows how to make the curve start at the origin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift/Translate the curve to the origin:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[54 {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10 + 12.5/54} + {45, -28, 40}, 
{t, -10, 10}], Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, Scaled[.015]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am not sure if I phrased my question correctly. I want to be able to have a helix start at the origin and have the curve cross the point(54,0,12.5). Also the  + {45, -28, 40} , is that the part that shifts the curve?

Comment: The constant vector just shifts the curve. You need to figure out what your question is: there are an infinite number of hellixes that start at the origin and go through any given point.

Comment: Well the problem is just to create a helix on mathmatica that starts at the origin and hits the point (54,0,12.5).

Comment: I do appreciate you being patient with me though.